# Decidable languages

Tags: computability, formal-languages

I have been trying to understand Turing machine in a intuitive way and most of the resources I find are filled with the mathematical terms and notations. I agree that its because of the fact that in mathematics we cannot afford ambiguity. Having said that I want to know the intuitive meaning of the decidable language.

After reading various resources I could say that the DECIDABLE languages are:

> For all string `s` in the Languages L if there exists a Turing machine
>   which HALTS either by ACCEPTING or REJECTING the string `s`.

I know that there are similar questions asked but I need to know if I am clear in my understanding.

Comment: It is hard to judge whether or not your understanding is correct. The formulation is definitely wrong - it is not even a properly formulated sentence. Better get that correct first. It doesn't make sense for someone else to fix your formulation, because then you won't learn if your understanding is correct.

Comment: I can write a Turing machine that always halts, and when you run it on a string of even length it returns 1, and when you run it on a string of odd length it returns 0. That means the set of strings of even length is decidable, because there is a machine that can "decide" whether an arbitrary string is in the set. All decidable sets follow the same pattern: there is some machine that says "1" for strings in the set and "0" otherwise.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I think you didn't get my point I want to know the gist of the topic and not to write some research paper. I want to understand in the way I can remember without noticing any mathematical notation. Having said that if there is something wrong in the plain English statement then please let me know,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. A language $L$ is decidable if there exists a Turing machine such that any time you give it a string from $L$ as input, it will always halt, either accepting or rejecting the string. Such a Turing machine is called a *decider* for the language, because it decides whether a given string is in the language or not.

A *semidecidable* (or *recognizable*) language is similar, but here the Turing machine does not need to always halt. A *recognizer* for a language only needs to halt with accept if given a string that is in the language, whereas when it is given a string not in the language, it may reject or never halt.